# White Space on Right Side of site. only on chrome mobile

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

Byenicotine.com

Initially I had the issue of white space on the right side of the page. 
Then I added overflow-x:hidden. and the problem disappeared in all browsers
except when i use chrome mobile.

any Ideas??

Comment: Where are you using `overflow-x:hidden` in the body tag?

Comment: Change `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { .ico{ visibility: hidden; } }` to `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some element with fixed width (400px)  that givess you whitespace on right. You can check it with inspect element on browser.

1. Open dev tools (F12 or right click > Inspect elemnt)
2. Select responsive viewer (On chrome is upper left conrner)
3. Inspect white area and see what elemnt is sticking out and fix it in CSS;